# How is interface a multiple inheritance without an implemetaion

Tags: java, c#, inheritance

An interface is used to implement multiple inheritances. But interfaces do not have any implementations. And all we do is inherit the name of a method and implement the method wherever we like and however we like.

How are these multiple inheritances when I have to implement a logic over and over again and not having some common functionality that can just be reused?

Comment: ***Interface is used to implement multiple inheritance***, no is not

Comment: *But interfaces do not have any implementations* It can have. In java8 you can have default implementations.

Comment: THe pros and cons have beed weighed and the cons won. You issue is not as common as you think (because the different parents will __not__ often call for the very same logic) but the diamond problem is...

Comment: Can you please provide a code-example showing what you want to *achieve*? Not what you think what the solution is? Or is this a rather acaddemic question on the intenion why the developers of Sun/Microsoft chosed to implement the language in a way? Anyway Java and C# are quite different when it comes to interfaces. So which one you´re actually asking about?

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects here:

- Before Java8, Java interfaces would not contain "implementation"; therefore using interfaces did **not** lead to "multiple inheritance".
- Java8 introduces default / static methods for interfaces; making it possible to "inherit" behavior from more than one superclass.

But: the java8 default methods were **never** meant to add a "generic trait" concept to Java (like you have in Scala for example).

Meaning: although Java8 allows for "multiple inheritance" that feature should not seen as such.

Beyond that: if you think that *inheritance* is meant to prevent *code duplication*, then you are going down the wrong rabbit hole. Yes, inheritance can help there. But the **primary** reason to say `A extends B` is because your **domain model** tells you to do so. Meaning: you create classes and relationships between them in order to build a **helpful** abstraction of reality. Something that helps you solving a functional problem.

In order to prevent code duplication, you very much prefer the good old [FCoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle!

Answer (score 2):

There is no multiple inheritance in Java to avoid the diamond problem (please read: http://www.journaldev.com/1775/multiple-inheritance-in-java).

However, an interface may extend from multiple interfaces. This is fine because the interfaces are only declaring the methods and the actual implementation will be done by concrete classes implementing the interfaces.

Comment: Used the avoid word

Answer (score 0):

In Java, interfaces are an alternate to Multiple inheritance. The interface is a mechanism to achieve abstraction. It only shows high level details of functions but don't provide implementation.

You can implement multiple interfaces in a class, implement some common functionality in this class and then extend other classes from it, so that you can re-use common functionality. This way you can avoid implementing same methods again and again.